# passing collection to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have multiple methods that return either a simple type (string, ..) & methods that return collections `Collection<Tuple<Model_name, string>>`

I tried with a simple `Collection<string>` at first but when i used a Tempdata to pass the collection to the view it doesn't work.

**Example :**

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     Collection<string> test_Q_Q = new Collection<string>();
     test_Q_Q.add("abcd");
     test_Q_Q.add("adbc");
     Tempdata["test"] = test_Q_Q;
     return view();
}
```

View:

```
<!--Bla Bla here-->
@foreach (var lst in Tempdata["test"])  //error here
{
      <li>  </li>
}
```

Comment: you are missing a `)`.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: `TempData` is useful for preserving values in session storage accross redirects. No need for that here as you return the view. Use `ViewBag` instead.

Comment: Why not pass the model directly to the view instead of using `TempData`?

Comment: I have to agree with David pass the model directly to the view. Also you might want to create a viewmodel to pass that data to the view (rather than the collection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue is that TempData is a stupid dictionary, and doesn't know that there's an IEnumerable stored in it's data.  If you really wanted to stick with this approach, simply cast the TempData to the appropriate type, like so:

```
@foreach (var lst in (Collection<string>) TempData["test"])
{
    <li> @lst </li>
}
```

Having said that, I don't think you should be using TempData.  What I recommend is using a strongly typed Model object that gets passed into the view, something like this in the controller:

```
var model = new MyCustomType();
model.ListOfStrings = new Collection<string>();
model.ListOfStrings.Add("foo");
model.ListOfStrings.Add("blah"); // You get the idea
return View(model);
```

Then, in your view declare the type like so at the top:

```
@model MyCustomType
```

And address it like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ListOfStrings)
{
    <li> @item </li>
}
```

At the very least, I hope you would use ViewBag instead of TempData.  As some of the comments have mentioned, TempData has a particular use, having to do with the lifetime of the HTTP request, and is not meant to be used the way you're using it.  Good Luck!

Comment: the thing is i have method that would go like this `info = getInfo()` where info is a collection that's why i am not sure the declare a specific model-view would work

Comment: Whatever type your 'info' object is, you could make that your model.  Model objects can be whatever custom type you can dream up.  If you give me more detail I can help, but otherwise I don't see an issue preventing you from the strongly typed model approach.

Comment: i have multiple methods most of them return a type of `Collection<Tuple<client, string>>` and i want to know if when i call something like `Collection<...> client_stuff = clientMethod()` and then pass that to the view like you did and the add part is taken care of inside the method, can i do it  this way?

Comment: Yes, you can pass whatever object you have in as the model object.  Build up the collection in whatever way you're comfortable with, pass that collection into the View(yourCollectionGoesHere), then make sure you declare your @model as whatever type you pass in... for example,      &amp:model Collection<Tuple<client, string>>

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your `foreach` loop test.

```
<!--Bla Bla here-->
@foreach (var lst in Tempdata["test"] )   //  Close 
{
      <li> ???? </li>
}
```